# Use ReadList with a condition for values of a certain column to handle huge (>1 GB) text files

Tags: import

Hello dear Mathematica community,
I would like to import a very large data set as efficiently as possible. The dataset consists of four columns and 115 million rows. For the display in Mathematica, however, only rows are needed in which the last of the four coordinates lies in a certain number interval between 0 and 1. This restriction would reduce the number of rows to less than one million in my case. Of course, one could now load the 2.2 GB into memory and then use the `Select` command to thin out the data. However, this procedure is very time-consuming and if not even impracticable due to the large amount of data. Unfortunately I have not found a specific entry on this or other forums. But during my internet research I came across the use of `Streams` and `ReadList`. So my question, is there any way to implement the data import I outlined without extreme processing time and lots of memory?  I have shown the first approach here by importing the first 200 entries from the header.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
str = OpenRead["mig_test.asc"];
SetStreamPosition[str, 147];
ReadList[str, Table[Real, {4}], 200, 0.1 < #4 < 0.15 &]
Close[str];
```

Unfortunately, of course, the selection criterion does not work this way. But how would something like this be realized? Or, how could it be realized in a different way?

Many thanks in advance.

Best,
Seb

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [`ReadList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html) or [`BinaryReadList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryReadList.html) and [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html).

For data of this size I recommend saving in ["Binary"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Binary.html) format; faster to read and write, and smaller file size.

Create a `"Binary"` data file.

```
SeedRandom[123];
vals = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0., .5}], {10000, 4}];
fn = CreateFile[];
Export[fn, vals, "Binary", "DataFormat" -> {"Real64"}];
```

Create `binReadListSelect` to read the rows and apply the `Select`.

```
ClearAll[binReadListSelect]
binReadListSelect[s_InputStream, type_, n_Integer, crit_] :=
 Module[
  {vals = BinaryReadList[s, type, n]}
  , If[vals == {}
   , Return[EndOfFile]
   , Select[vals, Apply[crit]]
   ]
  ]
```

Read in batches and [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) the `Select` criteria.  `Apply` is used here so that slots of column indices can be used in the criteria.

```
stream = OpenRead[fn, BinaryFormat -> True];    

recs = {};
sel = Null;
While[
 sel =!= EndOfFile
 , sel = binReadListSelect[
   stream
   , ConstantArray["Real64", 4]
   , 100
   , 0.1 < #4 < 0.15 &
   ]
 ; recs = Join[recs, Switch[sel, EndOfFile, {}, _, sel]]
 ;]

Close[stream]
```

Check results match what we would get by selecting from `vals`.

```
recs == Select[vals, Apply[0.1 < #4 < 0.15 &]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Clean up.

```
DeleteFile[fn]
```

Hope this helps.